# runtime error C++ program: glibc detected, munmap_chunk(), invalid pointer

Tags: c++, glibc

My C++ program (handling some calculation with matrices, see files below) crashes with the following messages:

> *** glibc detected *** ./matrix: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x08bfd068 ***

followed by the backtrace and memory map. It happens when I call the set-Method in the Matrix-class for the first time - yet I don't know what I'm doing wrong ... Every help (and general hints for improvement of my code) very appreciated!

**Array.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Array.h"

using namespace std;

Array::Array(){
    Array(10);
}

Array::Array(int size){
    data = new int[size];
    memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
    length = size;
}

Array::~Array(){
    delete [] data;
}

void Array::set(int pos, int value){
    if(pos < 0) pos = 0;
    if(pos >= length) pos = length-1;
    *(data + pos) = value;
}

int Array::get(int pos){
    if(pos < 0) pos = 0;
    if(pos >= length) pos = length-1;
    return *(data + pos);
}

void Array::print(){
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout << *(data + i) << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return;
}

/*works only for arrays of length 9*/
int Array::find_max(int data[]){
    int max = data[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
        if(data[i] > max) max = data[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```

**Matrix.h**

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H
#include "Array.h"

class Matrix{

    private:
        Array * data;
        int height;
        int width;

    public:
        Matrix();
        ...
};

#endif
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(){
    Matrix(10, 10);
}

Matrix::Matrix(int h, int w){
    height = h;
    width = w;

    data = new Array(height);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        *(data + i) = *(new Array(width));
    }

}

Matrix::~Matrix(){
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        Array * row = (data + i);
        delete row;
    }

    delete data;
}

void Matrix::set(int h, int w, int value){
    Array row = *(data + h);
    row.set(w, value);
}

...
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Array.h"
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 3){
        cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <m> x <n>" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    int m = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);

    Matrix * myMatrix = new Matrix(m, n);

    /*fill matrix randomly*/
    int guess, minus;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int r = 0; r < m; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < n; c++){
            guess = rand() % 1001;
            minus = rand() % 2;

            if(minus == 0) guess *= -1;
            std::cout << " set " << c << ", " << r << " " << guess << std::endl;
            myMatrix->set(r, c, guess);

        }
    }

    ...

    delete myMatrix;
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use a debugger and/or valgrind to narrow down your issue. That's way too much code to go through.

Comment: @Mat I did use a debugger, and narrowed it down to the method Matrix::set, but I included all the code in case it was necessary - but you're right of course - I'll clean that up to the important parths

Comment: The problem is that you use pointers and dynamic allocation. It's essentially impossible to write correct code with pointers and dynamic allocation. Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @KerrekSB Unfortunately it's a classroom assignment and I have to work with "native" arrays ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Matrix::Matrix(){
    Matrix(10, 10);
}
```

This is not doing what you think it is. It is just creating a **temporary matrix** and discarding it. That means the **height, width and data of the Matrix being constructed are not initialized there**.

I think your intention was to do the same thing as was done in `Matrix::Matrix(int h, int w)`. However you can not do it like that.

---

If you have **C++11** support you can use [**delegated construction**](http://www.nullptr.me/2012/01/17/c11-delegating-constructors/#.UYbAIBxqk4E) to do the same thing.

```
Matrix::Matrix() :  // <- Notice the colon
    Matrix(10, 10)
{
}
```

---

If you don't have C++11 support You have to do it manually

```
Matrix::Matrix(){
    height = 10;
    width = 10;

    data = new Array(height);

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        *(data + i) = *(new Array(width));
    }

}
```

or you can create another member function which does the common operations and call that from both constructors.

---

Another issue

```
Array row = *(data + h);
row.set(w, value);
```

You are copying the array row in to a new Array called `row`. **You don't have a copy constructor**. So the value of the pointers is copied directly. **When the function returns `row` is destructed** that means the memory pointed by `row.data` is `deleted` too and that means the data in the matrix is also affected **because it is pointing to the same thing**. See [**The rule of three**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Should be

```
Array* row = (data + h);
row->set(w, value);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I fixed this, but it is not the problem, as I always indicate the size of the matrix when creating one ...

Comment: @StringerBell See the edit. And also you have a similar problem to the first one in `Array::Array()`;